# Web Api Can't find Resource

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am trying to include Web APi in an ASp.NET application with Mvc. The application uses Identity Framework to authenticate itself.

I added a WebApiConfig

```
Imports System.Web.Http

Namespace ActualizadorApp.Api
    Public NotInheritable Class WebApiConfig
        Private Sub New()
        End Sub
        Public Shared Sub Register(config As HttpConfiguration)
            ' TODO: Add any additional configuration code.

            ' Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:="Api", routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}", defaults:=New With {
                Key .id = RouteParameter.[Optional]
            })

            ' WebAPI when dealing with JSON & JavaScript!
            ' Setup json serialization to serialize classes to camel (std. Json format)
            Dim formatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter
            formatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = New Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

In Global.Asax I have referenced this configuration

```
Sub Application_Start()
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)

    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(GetType(Decimal), New DecimalModelBinder())
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(GetType(Decimal?), New DecimalModelBinder())

End Sub
```

The authentication through / token is correct and returns the token correctly, but in the following GET calls to drivers the client returns me a 404
Could someone tell me that I'm doing wrong?

[image]

```
Imports System.Web.Http

<Authorize()>
Public Class TestController
    Inherits ApiController
    'public TestController() { }

    ' GET api/test
    Public Function GetValues() As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Return New String() {"value1", "value2"}
    End Function

    ' GET api/test/5
    Public Function GetValue(id As Integer) As String
        Return "value"
    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Api need to be registered before MVC Routes. And also you need to switch around the `GlobalConfiguration`

```
Sub Application_Start()
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()
    'Regsiter Web API routes before MVC routes
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)
    'MVC routes
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)

    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(GetType(Decimal), New DecimalModelBinder())
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(GetType(Decimal?), New DecimalModelBinder())

End Sub
```